# Shell Script to Enter a Directory (Folder Name Contains Spaces)

Tags: shell, unix, directory

I am writing a shell script to enter multiple folders.
I am currently storing the name of folder in a shell variable as so `path="October\ @012/"`.
If I do `cd $path` I receive the error **bash: cd: October\: No such file or directory**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the (principal) function of double quotes, and it's true in csh and *sh shells.

```
cd "$TARGET"
```

should do it.

Shell variables are expanded within `"..."` (unlike within `'...'`), but the quoted text is regarded as a single argument when the shell parses the command line to construct the strings which are passed to the program.

For example:

```
% ls -F
October @012/
% TARGET="October @012"
% cd $TARGET
bash: cd: October: No such file or directory
% cd "$TARGET"
% pwd
/tmp/t/October @012
%
```

Simple!

What you're doing wrong in your initial example is escaping the space *inside* the quotes. The space doesn't have to be escaped twice, and because this redundant `\` is appearing inside the quotes, it just inserts a backslash into the TARGET variable.  For example:

```
% TARGET="October\ @012"  # wrong!
% ls
October @012/
% cd $TARGET
bash: cd: October\: No such file or directory
% cd "$TARGET"
bash: cd: October\ @012: No such file or directory
%
```

This setting of `TARGET` would only work if the directory were named `October\ @012`, with a backslash in it (not recommended!):

```
% mkdir October\\\ @012
% ls -F
October\ @012/
% cd "$TARGET"
% pwd
/tmp/t/October\ @012
%
```

(**EDITED** to add example)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my folly in answering questions in the middle of the night during lack of sleep. You of course are right and I edited my answer before I saw that you had correctly answered the question.

Comment: Please help me with this:I am writing a shell script to enter multiple folders. I am currently storing the name of folder in a shell variable as so path="October\ @012/". If I do cd $path I receive the error bash: cd: October\: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank You Norman, This worked
and also thanks for the explanation, it helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I originally had written to recommend using curly braces. I wrote this when I had awoke in the middle of the night and have modified my answer.

First off it really depends on **which** shell you are writing your script in. If it is bash then you could try using quotation marks around your variable name:

```
TARGET="October @012"

cd "$TARGET"
```

This may work in other shells as well.  I would suggest you try it.

EDIT:

On re-examining this it appears you are escaping the wrong part in your expression. Try this:

```
path="October \@012"

cd "$path"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is taking October and @012 as two different folders.
But the folder name is "October @012" (space separated), I also tried ur method but got this error
bash: cd: October: No such file or directory

Comment: No, that's not the function of the `${...}` syntax. Here, the `${TARGET}` would be expanded to `cd October @012`, and then split at spaces into words, exactly as before. `${...}` is for the case where the expansion might get confused (for example `$TARGETX` vs `${TARGET}X`, or where you want to do other processing (compare `echo $foo`, where $foo is undefined, vs `echo ${foo:-bar}`)

Comment: That's what I get for answering questions when I wake in the middle of the night and can't seem to sleep. When I have used this in the past I have been solving the problem you Norman addressed, along with wrapping in quotes "" to address the OPs problem.

Comment: Please help me with this issue:
I am writing a shell script to enter multiple folders. I am currently storing the name of folder in a shell variable as so path="October\ @012/". If I do cd $path I receive the error bash: cd: October\: No such file or directory

Its urgent

Comment: Okay, so can you not use cd "$path" as both I and Norman have mentioned and accomplish what you are wanting?

Comment: Okay, I actually sat down and did some testing on this and it appears to me that from looking at how you define path (path="October\ @012") you are escaping the space (which inside quotes is unnecessary) but you are NOT escaping the @ (which even inside quotes IS necessary). If you change it to path="October \@012" and THEN do cd "$path" does it work?